# Condionally and Randomly update Pandas values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to build a scheduling app in python using pandas.

The following DataFrame is initialised where `0` denotes if a person is busy and `1` if a person is available.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'01.01.': [1,1,0], '02.01.': [0,1,1], '03.01.': [1,0,1]}, index=['Person A', 'Person B', 'Person C']) 

>>> df
          01.01.  02.01.  03.01.
Person A       1       0       1
Person B       1       1       0
Person C       0       1       1
```

I now want to randomly schedule `n` number of people per day if they are available. In other words, for every day, if people are available (`1`), randomly set `n` number of people to scheduled (`2`).

I tried something as follows:

```py
# Required number of people across time / columns
required_number = [0, 1, 2]

# Iterate through time / columns
for col in range(len(df.columns)):

    # Current number of scheduled people
    current_number = (df.iloc[:, [col]].values==2).sum()

    # Iterate through indices / rows / people
    for ind in range(len(df.index)):

        # Check if they are available (1) and
        # if the required number of people has not been met yet
        if (df.iloc[ind, col]==1 and
            current_number<required_number[col]):

            # Change "free" / 1 person to "scheduled" / 2
            df.iloc[ind, col] = 2

            # Increment scheduled people by one
            current_number += 1

>>> df
          01.01.  02.01.  03.01.
Person A       1       0       2
Person B       1       2       0
Person C       0       1       2
```

This works as intended but – because I'm simply looping, I have no way of adding randomness (ie. that `Person A / B / C`) are randomly selected so long as they are available. Is there a way of directly doing so in pandas?

Thanks. BBQuercus

Comment: can you explain the logic in words once? thanks

Comment: I added comments for each step I currently have. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can randomly choose proper indices in a series and then change values corresponding to the chosen indices:

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)):


    if sum(df.iloc[:,i] == 1) >= required_number[i]:


        column = df.iloc[:,i].reset_index(drop=True)

        #We are going to store indices in a list 
        a = [j for j in column.index if column[j] == 1]


        random_indexes = np.random.choice(a, required_number[i], replace = False)


        df.iloc[:,i] = [column[j] if j not in random_indexes else 2 for j in column.index]
```

Now `df` is the wanted result.